# When using Microsoft's CodePush on a React Native app, is there a way to force a user into a rollout that is not at 100% yet?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

We're adding [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) support to a React Native app. When we release an update we usually roll it out to 5% of our users first. Our QA team would like to be able to verify that an update is working fine on production before we increase this rollout to 100%.

**Is there a way I could force a user into a CodePush rollout?** I'm thinking something along the lines of a user going into the secret admin screen of the app and clicking a "*force CodePush update*" button; then that user would automatically get the update even if their device is not in that 5% rollout.